# ¿Cómo cambiar el color de una curva cuando los valores aumentan?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Tengo un conjunto de datos, a veces algunos valores aumentan en comparación con los anteriores.

```
resultsCos = [(0, 0.4235497237569061), (0.005, 0.4235497237569061), (0.01, 0.4238950276243094), (0.015, 0.42382596685082874), (0.02, 0.42375690607734806), (0.025, 0.42230662983425415), (0.03, 0.4210635359116022), (0.035, 0.41671270718232045), (0.04, 0.40835635359116024), (0.045, 0.3966850828729282), (0.05, 0.3770027624309392), (0.055, 0.3546270718232044), (0.1, 0.25041436464088396), (0.06, 0.3301795580110497), (0.065, 0.30738950276243093), (0.07, 0.2892955801104972), (0.075, 0.27603591160220997), (0.08, 0.2653314917127072), (0.09, 0.2553867403314917)]
```

Logré hacer un grafico con el codigo siguiente :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
# plot results Cosinus similarity
target = resultsCos
zip(*target)
plt.scatter(*zip(*target))
plt.xlabel('treshold/distance')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.title('Accuracy of cosine according to the distance')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero realmente no notamos cuando ha habido una mejora, y me gustaría destacarlo.

¿Cómo cambiar el color de una curva cuando los valores aumentan? ¿Y devolverlos al color original cuando no aumentan?

¿Cuál es el método para cambiar el color de acuerdo con el valor anterior?

Comment: A ver si te he entendido, lo que quieres es marcar los puntos que tienen un valor de `y` (accuracy) mayor que el punto que le precede en la gráfica. Si no me equivoco esto solo ocurre en tu ejemplo con el tercer punto (0.01, 0.4238950276243094), el resto siempre son inferiores al que le precede. ¿Es esto?

Comment: @FJSevilla Si !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La idea en este caso podría ser simplemente  proporcionar una lista de colores a `scatter` mediante su argumento `c`, de forma que coloree cada punto en base a ella.

Para obtener la lista, lo primero que tenemos que hacer es ordenar la lista de puntos para que los puntos estén ordenados en función de su coordenada x. Hecho esto basta con ir comparando cada elemento con el anterior e ir creando el mapa de colores, se puede hacer de varias formas, por ejemplo:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



resultsCos = [(0, 0.4235497237569061),
              (0.005, 0.4235497237569061),
              (0.01, 0.4238950276243094),
              (0.015, 0.42382596685082874),
              (0.02, 0.42375690607734806),
              (0.025, 0.42230662983425415),
              (0.03, 0.4210635359116022),
              (0.035, 0.41671270718232045),
              (0.04, 0.40835635359116024),
              (0.045, 0.3966850828729282),
              (0.05, 0.3770027624309392),
              (0.055, 0.3546270718232044),
              (0.1, 0.25041436464088396),
              (0.06, 0.3301795580110497),
              (0.065, 0.30738950276243093),
              (0.07, 0.2892955801104972),
              (0.075, 0.27603591160220997),
              (0.08, 0.2653314917127072),
              (0.09, 0.2553867403314917)]


normal_col = "darkCyan"
up_col = "coral"

res = sorted(resultsCos)
iterator = iter(res)
next(iterator) # Decartamos el primer punto

colors = [up_col if val[1] > res[i][1] else normal_col
              for i, val in enumerate(iterator)]

# El primer punto no es comparado con nada
colors.insert(0, normal_col)

plt.scatter(*zip(*resultsCos), c=colors)
plt.xlabel('treshold/distance')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.title('Accuracy of cosine according to the distance')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Si partimos de unos datos más propicios como una curva sinusoide podemos verlo mejor:

```
from math import sin, pi
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

signal =  [(x, sin(2 * pi * x / 100 / 2)) for x in range(0, 1000, 10)]

normal_col = "darkCyan"
up_col = "coral"

iterator = iter(signal)
next(iterator) # Decartamos el primer punto
colors = [up_col if val[1] > signal[i][1] else normal_col
              for i, val in enumerate(iterator)]

# El primer punto no es comparado con nada
colors.insert(0, normal_col)

plt.scatter(*zip(*signal), c=colors)
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]